# Get Name of the field javascript using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that looks like:
`{"id":1,"name":"aaa"}`

in my client side i have the following:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <td>
       {{here i want to get for example id or name}}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{order}} // here i have 1 in the first row and aaa in the second row
    </td>
</tr>
```

Anyone knows how to get the type of the object's value?(as i showed above)

thank you!!

Comment: You probably want to iterate an array of objects rather than properties of an object?

Comment: no, i actually want the property as well.

Comment: thank you vision. 
i didn't saw this question while i searched for solution
it works!!